# Using JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest

I have a REST API that returns a list of tasks in JSON Format, I decode it into an array
using :

```
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response,true);
```

and am having trouble in using that array.

EDIT : Sorry for modifying question but the `curl_response` is

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Api key is misssing"
}
```

When I login there is an API key in JSON response, I don't know how to use further. That key is required for authentication in any further call of API. How to include that apikey in my request header for further curl calls?

The response is of the form (as tested using Advanced REST Client in Chrome):

```
{
    error: false
    tasks: [5]
        0:  {
            id: 2
            task: "v@q.com"
            status: 0
            createdAt: "2014-10-21 21:42:48"
        }-
        1:  {
            id: 3
            task: "Inter Nam"
            status: 0
            createdAt: "2014-10-21 21:42:58"
        }-
        2:  {
            id: 4
            task: "Vamos"
            status: 0
            createdAt: "2014-10-21 21:43:04"
        }-
        3:  {
            id: 5
            task: "El Mundo"
            status: 0
            createdAt: "2014-10-21 23:12:33"
        }-
        4:  {
            id: 6
            task: "El Clasico"
            status: 0
            createdAt: "2014-10-21 23:12:45"
        }-
    -
}
```

I tried to decode the above response in an array `$decoded` and then I want to display each task in a loop, get total no. of tasks..etc. --------------------------------(1)
Using `Count($decoded)` I get 2 which is clearly wrong, also I am unable to to get the individual tasks using :

```
foreach($decoded as $task) {
    echo $task["task"];
}
```

How to implement (1) ?

Comment: You need to open up the `tasks` item; `foreach ($decoded['tasks'] as $task)`.

Comment: Post the raw responce from your CURL call, as that data structure is not valid JSON which might be the reason you are having a problem, or you have changed it somehow before pasting in in your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly How to get the raw reponse from CURL call ?

Comment: Just echo `$curl_response`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I did that and now I have to send api key as a request header in curl call. So, as said i just append the api key at the end of url or is there any other way too?

Comment: Well at least that is valid JSON, but now I am confused. So in fact you have not got a valid reply from you curl call. Maybe this is in fact a completely different question completely. Maybe you should ask another question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks again. i have to pass the api key as authorization header. so anything other than just appending is needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another level above what are you trying to access. Try this:

```
$tasks = $decoded['tasks'];
foreach($tasks as $task) {
    echo $task["task"];
}
```

Comment: I am sure you must be right but It isn't working for me.

Comment: I get no results . How can I check if my curl response is correct ?

Comment: Hmm you already said it was ok. You could just echo out `$curl_response`?

Comment: I thought I would need some function.... yes it is wrong {"error":true,"message":"Api key is misssing"}

Comment: I am sorry but can you tell how to include api key in the request header in Curl ?

Comment: If it's a GET variable, just add it to the URL. If it's a POST parameter, do `$data = array('apikey' => '12345'); curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: I have a Get call so I can just append it to url like /notes/12333

Comment: thanks again. i have to pass the api key as authorization header. so anything other than just appending is needed ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but One last help, I have a GET Call so do concatenate apikey with url or something more ?The link was for post only , right ?

Comment: Hmm... sounds like you haven't actually gone through the authentication process with the server yet. You'd better make a new question for that, it's getting beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: actually , i have the api key after login

Comment: OK. Better check with the api docs then, to see what you need.